# Symfony Form Doctrine

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity developer and comment and relationship Many comment to One developer. And I need form when I see all comment for developer and edit - add, delete. I create form but have error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.
```

entity Comment:

```
class Comments
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="talent_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $talent;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="added_by", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
private $added_by;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
private $comment;
```

entity Developer:

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/////
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="talent",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $comments;
```

and form

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('comments', 'text', array('label' => 'Comment', 'required' => false))
        ->add('tags', 'tags', array('label' => 'Tags','required' => false))

        ->add('save', 'submit');
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer',
        'validation_groups' => array('personal_information')
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'developer_for_admin_information';
}
```

Maybe need form in form but how do this I dont know, help please

Comment: I rolled this back to its original state, to match the answer you had received. If you have a new question to ask, please do so as such.

Comment: @shuba I downvote because you keep changing the question.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get has nothing to do with the Entity or Form, but with your Twig template `form_div_layout.html.twig`. You're probably trying to do something like:

```
<div class="developer-comments">
    {{ comments }}
</div>
```

But `comments` (or whatever the variable on line 13 in your template is called) is a collection, so you should use `{% for %}` instead, like this:

```
<div class="developer-comments">
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <div class="comment">{{ comment }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: @shuba.ivan Well, you pasted an entire other error now. This one pretty much says it all. You do not have a `getComments()` method and the `$comments` property is protected, not public. Hence your view cannot get the comments data. Best is to add a public `getComments()` method. You can use `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` to have all getters/setters automatically generated.

Comment: if I add comment from list I have $form->isValid() = false and:
 0 => FormError {#1379 ▼
              -message: "This value is not valid."
              #messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
and not flush and pesrsist entity, why?`

Comment: @shuba.ivan That's an entirely different question. That's the third time you edited the question and are asking something entirely else. This way, the Q&A format of StackOverflow is not really being followed, this is not a chat room. Please create different questions for different problems.

Comment: I do not know how to answer anymore, because you keep changing the question.